# My book says to make a program that tracks the amount of money a power user owes to the company using only switch statements

Tags: c, switch-statement

It had the same syntax error at all places marked with double forward slash, syntax error was "case label does not reduce to integer constant"

I can't use if statements because my book is dumb and hates if statements (but only in the switch statement chapter)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
double price;
int power;
char user,hrs;

printf("Enter what kind of consumer (R for residential, C for commercial, I for industrial): ");
scanf("%c",user);
printf("Enter amount of kilowatt hours used: ");
scanf("%d",power);

    switch(user)
    {
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
        price=6.00+.052*power;
        break;

    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        switch(power)
        {
        case (power>1000):    //
            price=60.00+(power-1000)*.045;
        case power<=1000:    //
            price=60.00;
        }
        break;

    case 'I':
    case 'i':
        {
        printf("Hours (P for peak, O for off-peak):");
        scanf("%c",hrs);

            switch(hrs)
            {
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
                switch(power)
                {
                case power>1000:    //
                    price=76.00+.065*(power-1000);
                    break;

                case power<=1000:    //
                    price=76.00;
                    break;
                } 

            case 'O':
            case 'o':
                switch(power)
                {
                case power>1000:    //
                    price=40.00+.028*(power-1000);
                    break;

                case power<=1000:    //
                    price=40.00;
                    break;
                }
                break;    
            default:
                printf("Business hour ID not recognized; try again");
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            printf("Consumer ID not recognized; try again");
            break;
    }

printf("Price is %f", price);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: you cannot replace if-statement with switch-statement

Answer (score 1):

The expressions in your `case` statements must be constants like `'p'`, not expressions like `power>1000`.

If you need to do expressions like `power>1000`, you should use `if`/`else` structures to handle all appropriate cases.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a case statement must be a constant integer.

You are free to use chars (e.g. 'a', 'x', etc) because they will be converted to integers by the compiler (using their ASCII code).

Using any other type of constant will yield unexpected and probably unpleasant results.

Besides, the compiler will complain (and rightly so) if you use the same value in two different case statements. This can be trickier than it seems. For instance :

```
#define WHATEVER 1
switch (xxx)
{
case        1 : return 1;
case WHATEVER : return 10; // error: duplicate case value
}
```

Frankly I don't think your exercise is such a good illustration of the practical use of a case statement.

99% of the times, the case values will come from an enumerated type, like for instance:

```
typedef enum {
   CMD_START,
   CMD_STOP
} Command;

function process_command (Command c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case CMD_START:
        do_start();
        break;
    case CMD_STOP:
        do_stop();
        break;
    default:
        panic ("unknown command %d", c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `switch` on `power`, the `case` targets must be constants.

Since you are actually only interested in the binary outcome of `power>1000`, you can apply the `switch` to that:

```
            switch(power>1000)
            {
            case 1:
                price=76.00+.065*(power-1000);
                break;
            default:
                price=76.00;
                break;
            }
```

The exercise is meant for you to understand that using a `switch` this way is very close to `if`-`else`. However, only do this to satisfy an academic exercise. No one would actually want to maintain code written this way. It is more natural to use `if`-`else`:

```
            if(power>1000)
            {
                price=76.00+.065*(power-1000);
            }
            else
            {
                price=76.00;
            }
```